# Question: How do you spell Tel-Aviv in Russian?

Tags: перевод

I translated Tel-Aviv, Israel into тель-авив, Израиль but I am not sure if there should be a "-" between the two words or not.

Comment: It should be capitalized (the both parts), otherwise correct.

Comment: In general you can figure it out by going to Wikipedia on a toponym and noticing how the corresponding article in Russian is called. And vice versa for any widespread language.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "Тель-Авив, Израиль". As it was mentioned in comments, you can use Wikipedia for translation of so popular words.